# Angular JS: sending data from select field via POST with $httpParamSerializerJQLike

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form in Angular JS. I submit it with

```
$scope.processForm = function() {
    $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'info_upload.php',
        data    : $httpParamSerializerJQLike($scope.formData),
        headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });

};
```

One of the fields is a select. In the html:

```
<select ng-model="formData.frecuencia" ng-options="frecuencia as frecuencia.label for frecuencia in frecuencias" class="form-control" required>           
</select>
```

In the js:

```
$scope.frecuencias = [{
    value: 1,
    label: 'Una sola vez'
}, {
    value: 2,
    label: 'Una vez a la semana'        
}, {
    value: 3,
    label: 'Una vez cada 2 semanas'        
}, {
    value: 4,
    label: 'Una vez al mes'        
}];
```

When I submit it, the data gets formatted like this

```
frecuencia%5Bvalue%5D:2
frecuencia%5Blabel%5D:Una+vez+a+la+semana
frecuencia%5B%24%24hashKey%5D:object%3A23
```

Which does not work fine with my php, which expects only 'frecuencia'.

I have other input fields and they work fine.

How could I solve it? If you want to see it in action, you can check http://www.profesionalista.com/limpiadores/reserva.html

Comment: You're assigning an object (one of your `frecuencias` items) to `formData.frecuencia` and the serializer is working as expected. What form **exactly** would you like it to transform the data in to?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to send the `value` property, ie

```
frecuencia=2
```

Change your `ng-options` expression to

```
"frecuencia.value as frecuencia.label for frecuencia in frecuencias"
```